# Whats the appropriate Filter syntax for Powershell?

Tags: azure-powershell

What is wrong in my filter?

Get-Mailbox -Filter  { ( ArchiveStatus -eq 0 ) -AND ( RecipientTypeDetails -eq UserMailbox ) }

Cannot bind parameter 'Filter' to the target. Exception setting "Filter": "Invalid filter syntax. For a
description of
the filter parameter syntax see the command help.
" ( ArchiveStatus -eq 0 ) -AND ( RecipientTypeDetails -eq UserMailbox ) " at position 58."
At C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_1retngr4.15m\tmp_1retngr4.15m.psm1:19986 char:9

- ```
      $steppablePipeline.End()
  ```
- ```
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-Mailbox], ParameterBindingException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingFailed,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.GetMailbox

Answer (score 0):

You should use this format:

```
Get-Mailbox | Where-Object {$_.ArchiveStatus -eq "0" -and $_.RecipientTypeDetails -eq "UserMailbox"}
```

See reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients-in-exchange-online/manage-user-mailboxes/use-powershell-to-display-mailbox-information#display-mailbox-information-with-exchange-online-powershell).

Answer (score 0):

Put 0 and UserMailbox in quotes.